# How to close a question as duplicate of multiple posts?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I've seen a question, which was closed as a duplicate of multiple posts.

For example, here:

[image: Duplicate of multiple posts]

But if I go to the flagging menu in a duplicate question, there isn't an option 'flag as duplicate':

[image: Flagging menu]

So, how was the post above closed?

Comment: See also [*Gold tag-badge holders and moderators can now edit duplicate links* (Meta.SE)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/242059).

Comment: You can't flag to close because it's already closed.